# What is the fastest but not venomous snake?

Tags: zoology

Is it known which non-venomous snake can attack most quickly? I guess it is a snake that attacks its opponent by bites, and not some kind of constrictor.

Comment: black mamba (?)

Comment: @WYSIWYG Its venomous.

Comment: ohh okay.. I missed it... sorry..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest non venomous snake is arguably the [Eastern Coachwhip](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masticophis_flagellum_flagellum) with a top speed of upto 10 mph ([reference](http://entertainment.news-leader.com/outdoors/thisweek/1021-Easterncoa-206629.html)). If it feels cornered, it will attack with bites but otherwise, it prefers to flee.